# how to write powers in texttt

Tags: gap

I'm trying to write

```
\texttt{gap> M:=Group(r*u^2*d^-1*b*d^-1);}
```

exactly this way. But latex return an error because of the powers.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{gap> M:=Group(ru\^{}2d\^{}-1bd\^{}-1);}

{\ttfamily gap> M:=Group(ru\^{}2d\^{}-1bd\^{}-1);}

\verb|gap> M:=Group(ru^2d^-1bd^-1);|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are trying to do verbatim text. Therefore, I would suggest using the `\verb` command.

```
\documentclass[preview, border=.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Lorem \verb|gap> M:=Group(ru^2d^-1bd^-1);| ipsum
\end{document}
```

Output: [image: LaTeX output]